# redmine - restore admin user after a db:reset

Tags: redmine

I installed Redmine locally to practice configuring it. After a while, I ran

```
bundle exec rake db:reset db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

to reset the database and start over. Now if I try to login, Redmine no longer has the default root user (user = admin, password = admin). This is the default user created during the initial install. 
Should I have used some other way to clear the database that would have left me a Redmine admin user?
How do I now add an admin user to Redmine? I can access the MySql database by using the console.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my own question. I should have also done: "rake redmine:load_default_data". However, this did not work until I first deleted the database, recreated it and ran "rake db:migrate" first.